# Is it a good idea to use Cloud FireStore for location updates only?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, location, latitude-longitude

In an app, we have to update the live location of the technician on our server, but that location won't be viewed live. It would only be seen for a particular time. Let's say the manager wants to see the Job Map, to know where the technicians are at our particular time, and will only require the technician's last location.

We are considering not updating the technician's location on the server directly, as they are not required to be viewed live and would require a lot of API calls.

**Possible solution:**

The solution that we are considering is to update the technician's live location on Firestore. When the manager wants to see the Job Map we can fetch the technician's last location from Firestore.

I'm wondering if it is a good strategy and trying to identify the potential issues.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if it is a good strategy and trying to identify the potential issues.

It's not about issues as it's about costs.

> We are considering not updating the technician's location on the server directly, as they are not required to be viewed live and would require a lot of API calls.

In this case, the best solution I can think of would be to save the technician's location locally and sync with the Firestore servers on demand.

> The solution that we are considering is to update the technician's live location on Firestore. When the manager wants to see the Job Map we can fetch the technician's last location from Firestore.

While Firestore can serve your purpose, please also note that there is another Firebase product called the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) that can also be useful in such situations. The difference between these two types of databases is that in Firestore the writes are billed while in the Realtime Database, the writes are free of charge. Since you say that you're not going to update the technician's location in Firestore in real-time time, then Firestore will not be so costly. But it's up to you to decide which is better, also considering the fact that both databases can hold and serve such information with no issues.

Comment: Hey Asad. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?